# VPS: Disabled internet connection. Access to VPS lost

Tags: connection, windows-server-2003, vps

I was using RDC to connect to my VPS. Once connected, by accident I disabled Internet Connection option on the VPS. I have lost connection to my VPS Support is actually offline.

What can be done now ? How I can fix this problem?

Comment: 1) Either contact your provider so they can log in locally, or 2)Gain acces without RDP (e.g. via DRAC, HP ILO etc, assuming this VPS is on real hardware or that a similar access is provided). or 3) Trigger a clean reinstallation via whatever method your ISP offers.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your VPS provider who'll be able to restore the connection. They may charge you for this, though, because it's user error.

Comment: I tried to ping my VPS address, not works..

Comment: What did you do? Make yourself an answer :)